# Where to start developing VR apps for Android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, oculus, google-vr

Can anyone please recommend me an SDK to start with VR(from the list of Cardboard SDK,Daydream,Unity SDK and Oculus)keeping in mind that I'm fairly good at Java only and have developed apps using Android Studio.
Any reference links would also help much.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Unity, Google Cardboard is best for now.

[Google Cardboard Introduction](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/#features)

[Unity Cardboard SDK and Samples](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download)

[Another Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/116805/make-vr-game-unity-google-cardboard)

> I'm fairly good at Java only and have developed apps using Android
>   Studio

You have to [learn C#, Unity API](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting). Its similar to Java but you still need to learn it.

Comment: thank you. someone had to tell me to learn C#, and you're right! :)

Comment: @onexf You welcome! Since you know Java, that should be easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

[jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) is another option. It's a game engine completely written in Java. It has a cardboard integration (of my own creation) with examples here: https://github.com/neph1/jme-cardboard .
Updating answer now that cardboard is a bit outdated:
There is now a GoogleVR integration in progress as well. It resides here: https://github.com/nordfalk/gvr-android-jme